overding an async function in odoo js
so I'm working on POS I added a custom qr code to the receipt generated but now I'm getting an encoding error because the async function to decode the image is set to time 0 - I want to override that function
the function is
odoo.define('point_of_sale.ReceiptScreen', function (require) {
    'use strict';

    const { Printer } = require('point_of_sale.Printer');
    const { is_email } = require('web.utils');
    const { useErrorHandlers } = require('point_of_sale.custom_hooks');
    const Registries = require('point_of_sale.Registries');
    const AbstractReceiptScreen = require('point_of_sale.AbstractReceiptScreen');
    const { useAsyncLockedMethod } = require('point_of_sale.custom_hooks');

    const { onMounted, useRef, status } = owl;


    const ReceiptScreen = (AbstractReceiptScreen) => {
        class ReceiptScreen extends AbstractReceiptScreen {
            setup() {
                super.setup();
                useErrorHandlers();
                this.orderReceipt = useRef('order-receipt');
                const order = this.currentOrder;
                const partner = order.get_partner();
                this.orderUiState = order.uiState.ReceiptScreen;
                this.orderUiState.inputEmail = this.orderUiState.inputEmail || (partner && partner.email) || '';
                this.orderUiState.isSendingEmail = false;
                this.is_email = is_email;

                onMounted(() => {

                    setTimeout(async () => {
                        if (status(this) === "mounted") {
                            let images = this.orderReceipt.el.getElementsByTagName('img');
                            for (let image of images) {
                                await image.decode();
                            }
                            await this.handleAutoPrint();
                        }
                    }, 0);
                });

I want to change it to
        await this.handleAutoPrint();  
    }
}, 1000); 

I tried extending the class but the first code runs then mine which should not be the case

but the first code runs then mine which should not be the case why would you think that? a time out of 0 will execute before a time out of 1000

overriding means altering the behavior, so the 0 should become really irrelevant. OP you are likely overriding it too late... Put up a breakpoint and see when it gets called for the first time, chances are you'll be surprised.

why I want override the 0 to 1000 or 500 is I have a custom function that is adding a custom qr code with data fetched from an api so on the actual receipt the qr code is okay but since there's an autoprint function which setimeout = 0 it's not giving the qrcode time to be decoded in await image.decode();

Can you provide more information? how are you doing it? Class above is the root component of receipt screen, show how you are doing
